# Как можно определить высоту/ширину svg-спрайта и записать ее в файл (через CLI под Mac или Linux)?

Tags: css, svg, imagemagick, svg-спрайт

Вообще пытаюсь создать svg-спрайт с помощью npm-пакета **svg-sprite**. В итоге получаю примерно такой спрайт (для 2-х картинок):

```html
...
<svg viewBox="0 0 108 54" ...>
  <svg height="54" width="54" viewBox="-2 -2 54 54" ...>
    <path d="...”>
   </svg>
  <svg height="54" width="54" viewBox="-2 -2 54 54" ...>
    <path d="...”>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

Для определения размера выходного спрайта в CLI использую команду **identify** из утилиты **ImageMagick**. Например, так

`identify -format '%w' icons-test.svg`

или сразу пишу в файл

`echo "\$spriteWidth = $(identify -format ‘%w’ icons-test.svg)px" >> styles.styl`

**Проблема в том**, что в итоге в файл записывается ширина не всего спрайта (108), а только последнего изображения, входящего в него (54).

**Подскажите**, что делаю не так, как поправить? Либо посоветуйте альтернативный способ решения задачи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположительно, imagemagick-овский SVG-декодер не понимает некоторые внутренние SVG теги. 
Посоветовали предварительно сконвертировать файл в другой формат, например так:

```
convert icons-test.svg mvg:- | identify -format '%w' mv
```

Для меня это сработало. Иногда, правда, выдаются ошибки вроде таких:

```
identify: non-conforming drawing primitive definition 64' @ error/draw.c/RenderMVGContent/4361.
```

Но все равно ширина/высота определяются верно.

Так что отмечу, как решение. Но если кто-то знает, чем вызваны/как избавиться от ошибок - пишите. Или если кто-то знает альтернативные способы решения - тоже.